# Query with sum, where condition and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do up a query for a table
hotel, roomtype, roomprice,
I am trying to get sum of roomprice as "total Single Rooms" 
where roomtype = single 
grouped by hotel
So I end up with hotel and "Total Single rooms"

I have been trying different ways but I can not seem to get that to work. Yes I am new to SQL lol

Thanks

Comment: Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: SELECT hotelNo,roomPrice,
    SUM(roomPrice) AS "Total Room Price",
    WHERE roomType = "Single",
FROM room,
GROUP BY hotelNo);

Answer (score 1):

You should accept MrVimes solution if it meets your requirement. If you want to include a hotel chain total you could use a with rollup to the group by for example:-

```
/*drop table t;
create table t (hotel varchar(3),roomtype varchar(1),price decimal(10,2));
truncate table t;
insert into t values 
('abc','s',10.00),
('abc','s',10.00),
('abc','s',30.00),
('abc','d',10.00),
('def','s',10.00),
('def','s',10.00),
('abc','d',10.00),
('abc','d',10.00),
('abc','d',10.00);
*/

select  case
            when s.hotel is not null then s.hotel
            else 'Total'
            end as hotel,
            s.totalsinglerooms
from
(
select  hotel, sum(price) as totalsinglerooms
from      t
where     roomtype = 's'
group   by hotel with rollup
) s
```

result

```
+-------+------------------+
| hotel | totalsinglerooms |
+-------+------------------+
| abc   |            50.00 |
| def   |            20.00 |
| Total |            70.00 |
+-------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you :) MrVimes was right on with the answer :0 thanks

Comment: Upvote for showing me 'rollup' which I might find useful in my own query jobs :)  I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select hotelno,sum(roomprice) as `Total Single Rooms` from room
where roomtype = 'single'
group by hotelno
having sum(roomprice) > 100
```

Comment: the table name is "room"

Comment: I do thank you :) I just changed the names where needed. I is so easy when you look at it and I was going all over the place lol.

Comment: No it is doing what it is suppose to do and now I have to add in there another part that only shows total over 100 so does that need another line or after the total single rooms?

Comment: @Wombat You can add "HAVING [Total Single Rooms] > 100" after the group by to only show lines with total over 100.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the over 100 requirement

Comment: I added that as you said and it returns no values where there should be 3 values

Comment: What are the totals per room when you leave out the having clause?  In other words,  are any of them over 100?

Comment: Was your reply to @jussius?   Did adding `having sum(roomprice) > 100` leave you with no rows?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!